# Jsp with javascript parameter inside javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jsp, onclick

I would like to insert a call to a function to get a parameter for my JavaScript `onclick`  function. What I would like to do is something like:

```
<input class="refreshbutton"
       type="button"
       id="searchUfficiPopup"
       onClick="javascript:postColorbox('/DeliDete/searchUfficiPopupBySettoreId', **'&settoreIdKey=${javascript:getSettoriId()}'**, 'tabUfficiForm', 'initScriptUffici')" 
       value="<fmt:message key="navigation.searchUffici"/>" />
```

This way Eclipse tells me the function `javascript:getSettoriId()` is undefined. I defined this function in an external .js file, loaded at runtime with jQuery's `.getScript`, so I would not like to insert it into the jsp (anyway I tried to insert it into the jsp but the IDE still says that the function is not defined).

The function postColorbox is defined as:

```
function postColorbox(url, parameters, formName, initScript)
```

The function `getSettoriId()` returns the value of a previously entered form element, `Settori`, which I need to perform a restricted query (I need to obtain all Uffici entities related to the selected Settori entity)

Told this, I would like to ask you experts:

1. Is it even possible to use a JavaScript function as a parameter of an onclick JavaScript function?
2. If I put this function to be called in an external .js file will the jsp be able to see it and call it?

Thank you all for your help!
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `onClick` on your `<input>` and do it with a jQuery event handler instead:

```
$('#searchUfficiPopup').click(function() {
    var settoriId = getSettoriId();

    postColorbox('/DeliDete/searchUfficiPopupBySettoreId',
                 '&settoreIdKey=' + settoriId,
                 'tabUfficiForm',
                 'initScriptUffici');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I just done it 2 minutes ago in a slighly different way: function searchUfficiPopupBySettori()
{
 postColorbox('/DeliDete/searchUfficiPopupBySettoreId', '&settoreIdKey=' + getSettoriId(), 'tabUfficiForm', 'initScriptUffici');
}  and in the onClick: onClick="javascript:searchUfficiPopupBySettori()"

Comment: Don't use `onclick`. Attach the event handler with jQuery. And even if you do use `onclick`, you don't need the `javascript:` prefix (it is only needed if you invoke JavaScript functions from an `href`).

Comment: I removed the various "javascript:" as you said. I saw this in a tutorial and thought it was necessary. Can you explain why should I use a jQuery handler instead of an onClick? I don't know the differences between the two. Maybe a crossbrowser misbehaviour of onClick? Thanks again

Comment: Well, it's just to keep JavaScript within JavaScript and don't "pollute" the HTML with references to it. With advanced enough JS (where you dynamically create HTML that you insert into your document) you will need to attach event handlers with JS anyhow, so mixing `onclick` with JS attachment just makes it messy and hard to maintain. Since you're using jQuery that makes event handler attachment so extremely easy, it's the only natural thing to do, really. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Calling functions from inside the HTML element is not a preferred way. If you can - just assign the element an id or class, and then add a listener to it using javascript on page load.

This way you don't have your data and operations mixed. It will be also easier to modify the code, as your code will be located in js files.